# Resize font and frame with pinchGesture when textView isScrollEnabled = false

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, instagram, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I have used `pinchGesture` to zoom-in and zoom-out `textView` using below code.

added `pinchGesture` to `textView`

```
let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handlePinch))
pinchGesture.delegate = self
view.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
```

**delagate**

```
@IBAction func handlePinch(recognizer:UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    if let view = recognizer.view as? UITextView {
        view.transform = view.transform.scaledBy(x: recognizer.scale, y: recognizer.scale)
        recognizer.scale = 1
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image]
[image]

Here is the possible solution i have applied but still not able to find perfect solution.

```
@IBAction func handlePinch(recognizer:UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    if let textView = recognizer.view as? UITextView {
        let font = textView.font!
        var pointSize = font.pointSize
        let fontName = font.fontName
        pointSize = ((recognizer.velocity > 0) ? 1 : -1) * 1 + pointSize;
        if (pointSize < 13) {
            pointSize = 13
        }
        if (pointSize > 100) {
            pointSize = 100
        }
        textView.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: pointSize)
    }
}
```

**Result**

[image]

Using above solution i am successfully able to increase font size but textView frame is not updating so text is getting cut off because textView frame is smaller.

**Expected Result**

Font will get increased and also frame will get update so it will look like simple zoom-in and zoom-out but without blurry.

Looking for best possible solution to increase font size with frame like **instagram** and **snapchat** is doing.

Thanks.

Comment: Looking at your comments in the answer, I'm guessing you are running into an issue with `UIFont` and how a custom font's vectors are implemented. (I know *just enough* about creating a custom font to be dangerous.) Two thoughts: (1) Do you know that your sources for solution are actually using a "canned" `UIFont`? Is it possible they created their own custom font - they do have the headcount and resources to do such a thing. (2) If they aren't, is it possible they "go around" `UIFont` by using `UIImage` and animating? Good luck figuring this out.

Comment: No i just want to zoom-in, zoom-out textView without font getting blurry

Comment: I get that. But I'm curious - are *you* making a wrong assumption? Is you belief that Instagram and SnapChat are doing what *you* think... animating a font size change without blurriness... wrong? If you believe you are wrong, then why? Do you know - again, I know just enough to be dangerous - the internals of `UIFont` to a point that you know this can be done? That's what I see is you "base" assumption.

Comment: Then how can they implemented this kind of functionality?

Comment: See my edit to my comments, and combine them with my first comment. Maybe they are using a custom `UIFont` - they surely have the resources to make a rasterized alphabet that can do this - or maybe they found an easier way - using a `UIImage` to "expand/contract" the textfield without blurriness a then showing the "finished" textfield. You ask a great question - I upvoted it - and I'm just thinking "outside of the box" because so far none has an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the to resize font and frame with `pinchGesture` when `textView` `isScrollEnabled = false`.

```
@IBAction func handlePinch(recognizer:UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
        if let view = recognizer.view {
            if view is UITextView {
                let textView = view as! UITextView
                if textView.font!.pointSize * recognizer.scale < 90 {
                    let font = UIFont(name: textView.font!.fontName, size: textView.font!.pointSize * recognizer.scale)
                    textView.font = font
                    let sizeToFit = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width,
                                                                 height:CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
                    textView.bounds.size = CGSize(width: textView.intrinsicContentSize.width,
                                                  height: sizeToFit.height)
                } else {
                    let sizeToFit = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width,
                                                                 height:CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
                    textView.bounds.size = CGSize(width: textView.intrinsicContentSize.width,
                                                  height: sizeToFit.height)
                }
                textView.setNeedsDisplay()
            } else {
                view.transform = view.transform.scaledBy(x: recognizer.scale, y: recognizer.scale)
            }
            recognizer.scale = 1
        }
    }
```

Comment: It create framing expansion issue while increasing font size with pinch zoom with single line of text.

Comment: @BhavikModi How can we fix that ?

Comment: Thanks @BhavikModi

Answer (score 7):

**Here is the code to resize font size along with frame on pinch zoom in/out using UITextView and isScrollEnabled = false**

```
@objc func pinchRecoginze(_ pinchGesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
   guard recognizer.view != nil, let view = recognizer.view else {return}

    if view is UITextView {
        let textView = view as! UITextView
        if recognizer.state == .began {
            let font = textView.font
            let pointSize = font!.pointSize
            recognizer.scale = pointSize * 0.1
        }
        if 1 <= recognizer.scale && recognizer.scale <= 10  {
            textView.font = UIFont(name: textView.font!.fontName, size: recognizer.scale * 10)
            let textViewSiSize = textView.intrinsicContentSize
            textView.bounds.size = textViewSiSize
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Smaller font size]

[image: Pinch zoom to larger font size]

**Updated answer to compatible with UITextView**

Comment: i am also able to do same using UILabel thats why i have mentioned that i need to achieve this using textView with isScrollEnabled = false

Comment: @PinkeshGjr Check Updated answer for UITextView

Comment: try using multiple line

Comment: I have tried and tested with multiple line of text and its working great. Please let me know if its not working with your setup.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try to enable scrolling in the beginning of your `handlePinch` method and disable it again at the end of pinching?:

```
@IBAction func handlePinch(recognizer:UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
  if let textView = recognizer.view as? UITextView {
    textView.isScrollingEnabled = true
    let font = textView.font!
    var pointSize = font.pointSize
    let fontName = font.fontName
    pointSize = ((recognizer.velocity > 0) ? 1 : -1) * 1 + pointSize;
    if (pointSize < 13) {
        pointSize = 13
    }
    if (pointSize > 100) {
        pointSize = 100
    }
    textView.font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: pointSize)
    let width = view.frame.size.width
    textView.frame.size = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    textView.isScrollingEnabled = false
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes but that will not change textView frame so when font is increased it will not visible because textView frame is same as old

Comment: I edited my answer, what if you call sizeToFit on the textView after you change the font?

Comment: textView.sizeToFit() will not increase width

Comment: Yeah you are right, I believe this can be solved by sizeThatFit method. Can you check my updated answer?

Comment: Yes that will but this is workaround only because when zoom level reach to main view width text position will change so it will not look like zoom-in zoom-out

Comment: What if you animate that process? Can you give it a shot? It still wouldnt be perfect, but maybe would look nice.

Comment: No i want it look much simple as zoom-in, zoom-out but it should be not blurry